# How can I use this shell command in control-m command line

Tags: control-m

How can I use shell command in control-m command line?
/Path/somescript.ksh 1>some.log 2>&1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily like below:-

```
MEMLIB="/Path/" <!-- example "/usr/bin" -->
MEMNAME="somescript.ksh" <!-- example ls -->

<AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARM1" VALUE="1>some.log"/>
<SHOUT DEST="xxx" MESSAGE="%%JOBNAME FAILED REVIEW DOC" URGENCY="U" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
<AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%PARM2" VALUE="2>&1"/>
<SHOUT DEST="xxx" MESSAGE="*N*2 %%JOBNAME HAS FAILED, REVIEW DOC" URGENCY="V" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
```

Now in reality it will execute like:-

```
/Path/somescript.ksh 1>some.log 2>&1
```

Please let me know if you need any more help.